# Why are @Valid annotations not considered by Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, validation

`@Valid` is not considered here and I can call the API with every string:

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account")
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
@Slf4j
public class AccountController {
    private final AccountService accountService;

    @GetMapping
    @ResponseBody
    public Account getAccountDetails(@Valid @Email @RequestParam final String email) {
        return accountService.getAccount(email);
    }
}
```

Here is my `main()`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableCaching
@EnableAsync
public class AccountApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AccountApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here my Spring Boot dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.8</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

Do I need to enable Spring Boot validation somewhere?

Comment: To have validation for method parameters you need to add `@Validated` to the controller. Which will create a proxy which will handle the validation. The `@Valid` usecase is only usable for either `@ModelAttribute` (when binding request parameters to an object) or `@RequestBody` when deserializing a request body into an object. It won't  do anything on a single paramater. Either add `@Validated` to the controller or create a wrapper object which has an `email` field which you can then annotate with `@Email`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All what was missing was the
`@Validated` annotation on the controller class (thanks @Boško):

```
@Validated
public class AccountController {
    private final AccountService accountService;
```

(btw the `@Valid` annotation does not work here!)

Answer (score 1):

You may have used an ambigiuous import.

Use `import javax.validation.Valid`
because Spring Boot 2.7 uses JavaEE

instead of `import jakarta.validation.Valid` which would be valid for Spring Boot 3.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected my question. I already use the proper import.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.7 uses JavaEE not JakartaEE. If this would be Spring Boot 3 this would be the correct advice, but here it isn't.

Comment: @M.Deinum Fartha suggested to use the JavaEE annotation instead if the JakartaEE annotation. Therefore I think his hint was right.

Comment: @M.Deinum I improved the answer and added your Spring Boot version hints

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure a validator bean:

```
@Bean
public Validator validator() {
    return Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
}
```

Then you apply the `@Validated` annotation and add a `BindingResult` parameter to the `getAccountDetails()` method, like this:

```
...
@Validated
public class AccountController {
    private final AccountService accountService;

    @GetMapping
    @ResponseBody
    public Account getAccountDetails(@Email @RequestParam final String email, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            // validation error handling
        }
        return accountService.getAccount(email);
    }
}
```

If there are any validation errors, the `BindingResult` parameter will be populated. You can read more about it here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be declared immediately after the model attribute, the \@RequestBody or the \@RequestPart arguments to which they apply: public com....Account com....AccountController.getAccountDetails(...)

Comment: Spring Boot already exposes this (as well as regular Spring BTW). The `BindingResult` is only for use with `@ModelAttribute` and `@RequestBody` none of which apply here. The `@Validated` on the class however is as that is the missing piece here.

Comment: I tried it with the validator-bean as well as with `@Validator` or `@Valid` on the controller class but it still does not work :-(